# Placing logo with Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have used following code to place logo on my site wpbarbers . com.
Everything works fine in Mozilla and Chrome but Internet Explorer and Safari are not showing logo.
Thanks for tip!

```
(function() {
  var logoHere, logoMain, text;
  text = document.querySelector(".header .header-inner .logo a");
  console.log(text);
  text.innerHTML = "";
  logoHere = document.querySelector(".header .header-inner .logo a");
  logoMain = document.createElement("img");
  logoMain.setAttribute("src", "http://wpbarbers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/wp-barbers-logo.png");
  logoMain.setAttribute("height", "143");
  logoMain.setAttribute("width", "300");
  logoMain.setAttribute("alt", "WP Barbers");
  logoHere.append(logoMain);
}).call(this);
```

Comment: When you say Mozilla, do you really mean [the browser with Mozilla in its product name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Application_Suite) or do you mean [the browser currently published by Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/new/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=getfirefox-com) (because you didn't call the other browsers Google, Microsoft and Apple)

Comment: "Internet Explorer and Safari" — Which versions? What do their error consoles say?

Comment: the question is why would you want to use javascript to add the logo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) not [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append). `append` is experimental and not what you are looking for in this case.

```
logoHere.appendChild(logoMain);
```